# Designing chat window

Tags: javascript, html, chat

I need some good tutorials on designing a chat window.I have the basic window designed but i want something lik in gmail,facebook...

thanks

Comment: Why would designing a chat window be something specific? Maybe you could just look for general design tutorials with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Do you just want to design the window, or do you need it to function?

Comment: no...i hav the basic window designed but need it look more attractive lik in gmail...

Answer (score 2):

A peculiar question!

Well, just look at another chat implementation (e.g. in Facebook), and take your design cues from there if you can't figure it out yourself.

At the most basic level in HTML, you will be designing a form, with some kind of chat viewing pane (perhaps just a large `textarea`), plus another textarea element and a "Submit" button for the current user to use when sending comments to the chat.

It's really not so hard.

The *hard* part is building the chat application itself. Obviously you can't do that solely with HTML and CSS.